# Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e INTERSECT?

Tags: sql

Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e INTERSECT? Alguém pode exemplificar também?

Comment: O INNER JOIN está bem explicado aqui: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join?rq=1)

Comment: Note que para fazer um INTERSECT, assim como UNION ou DIFFERENCE (ou EXCEPT), de duas queries tais queries deverão união-compatíveis e o resultado é um conjunto de linhas/registros com os mesmos atributos das queries envolvidas.

Answer (score 1):

As operações com INTERSECT e EXCEPT são realizadas com base na conversão implicita do resultado entre duas consultas.

As operações com INNER JOIN realizam um vínculo entre duas tabelas ou consultas por meio de um ou mais campos.

### Sintaxe

```
 <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> )    
 EXCEPT | INTERSECT 
 <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> )
```

### EXEMPLO

```
-- Uses AdventureWorks  

SELECT ProductID   
FROM Production.Product  
INTERSECT  
SELECT ProductID   
FROM Production.WorkOrder ;  
--Resultado: 238 linhas (produtos que tem WorkOrder)
```

Segue a referencia da documentação da Microsoft. [EXCEPT e INTERSECT](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql)

Comment: então eu fazer a seguinte consulta `select ProductID from FROM Production.Product a where exists (select null from FROM Production.WorkOrder where b and a.ProductID = b.ProductID)` seria equivalente ao exemplo da sua resposta? e no caso do `EXCEPT` poderia usar um `not exists`?

Comment: Neste caso seria equivalente sim. Mas tem um ajuste na `where`,  acho que digitou o `And` por engano e o `b` seria o alias da WorkOrder. No seu exemplo, ainda poderia incluir outras colunas no select que não teria nenhum problema. No meu exemplo com INTERSECT, para incluir uma coluna em um select, teria que incluir no outro também.

Comment: Foi erro de digitação mesmo.